# Using MQTT with HTTP Streaming Server

Tags: python, http, streaming, mqtt, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to use MQTT to receive messages while using a Streaming HTTP server to stream my picamera onto my 5000 port within the same file. This is causing my MQTT to be rather unstable and it cannot receive messages at time. May I know anyone has a solution to this? Thank you.

MQTT code

```
def on_connect(client,rc):
    if rc == 0:
        global Connected                
        Connected = True                 
        client.subscribe("picam/show")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global capture_image
    data = message.payload.decode("utf-8").replace("'", '"')
    d = json.loads(data)

    if d["action"] == "take pic":
        try:
            capture_image()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

client = mqttClient.Client("picam")  
client.on_connect= on_connect  
client.connect(broker_address, port=1884)      

# edited here to change loop_forever to loop_start 
client.loop_start()
```

Streaming HTTP Code

```
output = StreamingOutput()
camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
try:
    address = ('', 5000)
    server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: You seem to have two event loops. How do you make both run?

Comment: @KlausD. The client event loop forever is ran using client.loop_forever() and the server is ran using the server.serve_forever(). Not sure if it is because of these 2 loops that are causing the instability

Comment: If you run one of the event loop commands your code will not return from it. So, how do get to the other? Your two separate code blocks don't show how they run in combination.

Comment: @KlausD. Oh sorry instead of loop_forever, I used loop_start(). However, it still seems rather unstable and some mqtt packets are dropped at times. Do you know if it is able to have both mqtt and http streams at the same time? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by using threading :) ! Just in case anyone also faces this problem